# How to run RN tests with `debug` enabled in Detox?

Tags: react-native, detox

Is there a way to start React Native app on simulator with enabled `debug` mode (to have a connection to RNDebugger)?

Any flat for starting app / running detox?

Comment: Build your app in debug mode and that is what Detox will test.

Comment: I know, the question is about React Native debugger (that one which might be enabled/disabled via dev menu)

Comment: Well, you can shake the device using Detox to show the menu and enable debug.

Comment: I know that I can shake, question is how to do it programmaticaly

Comment: `await device.shake()`

Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: @leonatan and that issue was closed by you https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/403 especially strange that above you gave me that answers

Comment: That’s 2017, not sure if it’s still accurate. You can try and see.

Comment: I did, I can't control that menu. Just open the menu is not enough. Common. If I knew wat to try I would do that

Answer (score 2):

Ok, for those who didn't manage to find the issue (as well I me)

https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/403

> This is not supported and will not be implemented. When you use remote JS debugger, all JS calculation is performed on another process (Chrome) and Detox cannot sync your app reliably. You can read your logs after Detox finishes running your tests.

Update: as a workaround in BeforeAll I put sleep for 30 secs to reload app in debug mode